# Erro ao excrever data frame em Excel

Tags: python

Estou tentando extrair alguns dados e escrever em um arquivo excel. No entanto, eles vem com um shape=(1,209,26) o que gera o seguinte erro ao tentar passar para o .xlsx "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 209, 26)".
Como transformá-lo em um data frame em formato 2d?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking"

header = {
 "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs)
```

Comment: Diego, por favor, releia a sua pergunta e veja se faz algum sentido. Recomendo já acessar a [help], ler o guia de [ask] e analisar como montar um [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_html(r.text)` retorna uma lista com as tabelas da pagina, então você acessa as tabelas pelo indice, no seu caso a tabela está no indice 0

```
df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
```

df ja é uma DataFrame, não precisa fazer mais a conversao da ultima linha